# Run Facebook FQL Online

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Where can I run FQL queries online in my web browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/)'s the Facebook's official page with developer tools. There used to be an FQL console there, but it's no longer available. You can use the tools there to test other FB API though.

Edit: For an actual FQL test console, you can take a look at [this](https://github.com/splix/fqlconsole). It's not online like you wanted, but it's the next best thing that I could find when I went looking.

Comment: FQL is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher and no longer available

Answer (score 19):

> Where can I run FQL queries online in my web browser?

In Facebook Developers [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) Tool, in this format (using a simple example):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid = me()
```

**Update:**

Graph Explorer now has a dedicated FQL query window. Press the FQL button and enter your query as:

```
SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid = me()
```

Comment: It returns: `{"data": []}`. EDIT: Now you need to request access token and choose which permissions you need. Insufficient permissions will results in no data without any warning.

Answer (score 5):

go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and click the "FQL Query" button.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice online form:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/

Answer (score 1):

[query](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/) and [multiquery](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/) -- on either page, scroll down to find the Test Console

Answer (score 0):

FQL and Graph API explorers:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Just click the FQL option if you want to test FQL. Works wonderfully.

Comment: FQL is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher and no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

FQL is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher and no longer available